# Sending a android.content.Context parameter to a function with JNI

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a method that checks for internet connection that needs a Context parameter. The JNIHelper allows me to call static functions with parameters, but I don't know how to "retrieve" Cocos2d-x Activity class to use it as a parameter.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

and the c++ code is

```
JniMethodInfo methodInfo;
if ( !JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo( methodInfo,
    "my/app/TestApp", "isNetworkAvailable", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Z")) {
        //error
        return;
}
CCLog( "Method found and loaded!");
methodInfo.env->CallStaticBooleanMethod( methodInfo.classID,
methodInfo.methodID);
methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef( methodInfo.classID);
```

Comment: Can you tell me why do you need this context? Just to get getSystemService ?????

Comment: This is not the solution, but the descriptor for isNetworkAvailable is wrong. It should be: "(Landroid/content/Context;)Z". Note the L and Z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocos2dxActivity.java:
Add this line to Cocos2dxActivity: `private static Activity me = null;`
Remove this line from onCreate:

```
Cocos2dxActivity.context = getApplicationContext();
```

In its place put: `me = this;`

use :

```
(ConnectivityManager) me.getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Now you don't need to pass the context from your Jni... I know this is not the solution but for your case you don't need to worry about context from Jni.. You can simply do your work.

Hope this helps.. I used this way to send mail from android in my game. :)

Comment: Static attribute is probably the best solution here, and it also is retrievable with jni calls so I'll give it as correct.

Comment: I advice you edit the code with (ConnectivityManager) MyCocos2dxActivity.me.getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); so it shows it can work even if the isNetworkAvailable is in another class.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass Context object to JNI using the following method:

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_yournamespace_yourclassname_methodname( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jobject p_context);
}
```

on your java class use the following declaration:

```
public native static boolean methodname(Context p_context);
```

Now you can call the native function from your java code and pass a context a parameter.

as for getting your app class and use it, I'd use the following code (in the C++ part):

```
jclass yourAppClass = env->FindClass("my/app/TestApp");
jmethodID someMethodId = env->GetStaticMethodID(yourAppClass , "methodName", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Z");
jboolean retval = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(yourAppClass , someMethodId , p_context);
```

Comment: Correct but incorrect. Your code fix my call problems, but what I want is the actual dynamic context of the main application, and for that I need to retrieve it first from the c++ code.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic context? The main application context can be passed as an argument to your JNI call using getApplicationContext()

Comment: And that was my question, the snippet that does that, in CPP.

Answer (score 1):

The first error I see is that you are trying to get the method incorrectly.

`"(android/content/Context;)V"` means you are asking for a method that receives `Context` as a parameter and returns `void` which is not your case.

Your call should be something like this:

```
jclass aClass = env->FindClass("my/app/TestApp");
env->GetMethodID(aClass, "isNetworkAvailable", "(android/content/Context;)Z");
```

I am not completely sure how to pass a `Context` to `JNI` without breaking things or being sure it will work. But instead of passing it, you can call `getApplication()` and use it as a `Context`.

Comment: Even if I change the signature and function call, the problem remains. What the function does is to call OpenFeint, which requieres the main Activity. I sort of fixed it in the java code, but I would like to know how to get the app from cpp code in case I need it somewhere else.

Comment: @EfEs: That's not the code you are showing in your question. I am not sure how to do it then. I would recommend you digging into http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk to learn the answer.